# Using jQuery to insert PHP variable into form input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have been staring at this problem for hours, but my jQuery skills are quite basic, so please I need some help here.

I have a 3 form inputs.
When I click on one of the inputs it opens a bootstrap modal that contains my image gallery (which is populated by PHP), and below each image is an "Insert" button.

When I click the Insert button I wish to pass the title of that image back into the specific input field that I clicked.

I know this should be done with jQuery using "this" but just cant figure it out.

Here is my code so far:

The form fields

```
<form>
    <div>
    <input type="text" class="image_up" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="text" class="image_up" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="text" class="image_up" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
    </div>
</form>
```

My image gallery code (with insert button)

```
<?php
        $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC");
        if($query->num_rows > 0){
            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                $imageURL = '../../images/'.$row["file_name"];
                $imageTitle = $row['file_name'];
                $imageID = $row['id'];
        ?>
        <div class="image-gallery-item">
            <div class="image-gallery-img">
            <img class="gallery-img" src="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" alt="" />
            </div>
            <p class="mt-2"><?php echo $imageTitle; ?></p>
            
            <button onclick="insert('<?= $imageTitle; ?>')" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">INSERT IMAGE</button>
        </div>
```

My ineffective piece of jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".image_up").click(function insert(image){
    $(this).val(image);
  });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does this currently put into the input field, I don't have access to your database to fully test myself. Although I don't see the reason why you are calling this function when clicking in the input field unless that is something that is something for the rest of your project. Perhaps try moving the function out of the click and also at that point, I doubt you would need to wrap it in the ready function either. It looks like you only need to call it when you click the Insert button. Also it looks like you might be missing a curly bracket on your while loop. As well as the if statement.

Comment: @Aurange When I initially click the input field it populates with [object Object] and then when I click the insert button there is no change

Comment: Can you explain why you have it called when clicking into the input field, is there a reason for that? Like I said I would suggest moving the insert function out of the click function, and ready function as unless there is a specific reason you are doing that, I don't see a reason to wrap it in them like that, and that might also be preventing the insert function from actually being called when the button is clicked so the insert function call that the button is trying to call would be to a non-existent function.

Comment: I think I get it now. You need to be able to associate the input with the specific image. I'll see if I can't think of something. Do the individual inputs open up different galleries? How do you detect which gallery is loaded with each input?

Comment: That is what it does, or what you want it to do, because that doesn't work and gives me a TypeError saying the insert function doesn't exist, because well it doesn't, not in a way that the button would be able to access. If it is what you want it to do then yeah, I'm trying to think of a way to get that to work for you. If it does work then that kind of solved your question already no?

Comment: So you mentioned you are using Bootstrap right? $('#exampleModalCenter').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) { console.log("The calling element is:", e.relatedTarget); }); Put that into your Javascript and tell me what the console says.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".image_up").click(function insert(image){
    $(this).val(image);
  });
});
```

Should be changed to:

```
function insert(image){
  document.querySelector('input[data-caller=' + document.getElementById('exampleModalCenter').dataset.caller + ']').value = image;
}
```

Also add this:

```
$('#exampleModalCenter').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
  this.dataset.caller = e.relatedTarget.dataset.caller;
});
```

Then on all of of your form text input add data-caller="". And give each of them a unique value. Like:

```
<form>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="image_up" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" data-caller="first">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="image_up" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" data-caller="second">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="image_up" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" data-caller="third">
    </div>
</form>
```